# format.volume limit the decimal places?

Tags: pine-script

```
// Average daily volume - over last 3 months (63 trading days)
AvgVolInput = input(0.5, 'Minimum average daily volume (M) - Default 0.5M')
AvgVolMin = AvgVolInput*1000000
AvgVol = ta.ema(volume, 63)
AvgVolCondition = AvgVol >= AvgVolMin? color.green : color.red

table.cell(StockData, 0, 5, 'Vol ' + str.tostring(AvgVol, format.volume), bgcolor = AvgVolCondition, text_size = size.small)
```

I'm trying to use this to display the average volume for a given stock, but the table gives "Vol 3.822" - I'd like to round this to "3.9" so it doesn't make the table table wider than it needs to be.

Is there any way to control the decimals it's using? [example from $SPR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r53uz.png)

I tried rounding before applying the format, but that didn't work... tried some other things here: https://www.reddit.com/r/pinescript/comments/163usa4/formatvolume_but_remove_decimal_places/?sort=new

Another option may be to manually make my own equivalent of format.volume, by defining the volume ranges, but just seems a LOT cleaner to to it with PineScript...

So far no luck! I'm pretty new to this, but cobbled together a pretty good solution so far... just this left to fix up!